# Sum column value based on leng of row

Tags: pandas

I have a pd df and I want to sum my "Price" column based on the row length condition.

Fox example, assume:

```
row_len=5,
```

if

```
df['Year']=row_len,
```

I want to sum the `"Price"` column from 15.6 to 12.5.

Can someone help on the code?

```
      Year     Price
 0     1        15.6
 1     2        20.4
 2     3        24.8
 3     4        45.1
 4     5        12.5
 6     6        17.4
```

Comment: I want to sum from 15.6 to 12.5, i.e., 15.6+20.4+24.8+45.1+12.5.

Answer (score 0):

`year = 1` may not match `index = 0`, therefore:

**1) depending on the index using [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):**

```
row_len=5
df.iloc[0:row_len]['Price'].sum()
```

Output:

```
118.4
```

**2) depending on the value of year:**

```
year_value=5
rows_sum=df['Year'].eq(year_value).cumsum().shift().fillna(0).eq(0)
df.loc[rows_sum,'Price'].sum()
```

Output:

```
118.4
```

Comment: I am glad to help!. Could you accept and / or vote my answer?